# No FindBugs warning for null return value if annotated with @Nonnull

Tags: java, findbugs, notnull

I have annotated a method returning `null` with the `@javax.annotations.Nonnull` annotation but FindBugs does not generate any warnings on this.

```java
@Nonnull
public EventBuilder forCreateEvent() {
    return null;
}
```

Maybe I misunderstood the meaning of `@Nonnull` but I thought it means **Method will not return null**.

*Additional comment: Please see my comment below for the cause of the problem.*

Comment: FindBugs looks for `edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Guys, it was my stupid mistake. In my old old exclude filter configuration I excluded all null pointer related checks.

Comment: @OliverF. Please post an answer detailing how this was "pilot error" and include the configuration that caused the exclusion.

Answer (score 2):

The annotations that Findbugs understands are documented [here](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html).

At the time I originally answered this question, the `javax.annotations.*` annotations are not listed.  They are listed now.

Comment: FindBugs *definitely* understands `javax.annotation.Nonnull`. We've been using it for over a year. The linked page states that `jsr305` must be on the classpath. I think they merely list their custom annotations.

Comment: All FindBugs annotations are deprecated and you can see comments there telling you to use javax.annotations instead.

Answer (score 1):

As assylias said, May be its conflicting. Try changing it to

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull
public EventBuilder forCreateEvent() {
    return null;
}
```